# Encoding trouble: php api and java client program

Tags: java, php, json

I am sorry to post such a "noob question", but I can't solve my problem by myself.
I have a server-side script, written in php which returns different values, in this example all companynames which are stored in a MySQL DB.

-The column in the DB is encoded in UTF-8
-The php file is encoded in UTF-8

This is the server side script:

include_once('SQLHandler.php');
    $SQLHandler = new SQLHandler();

```
if(isset($_POST['command'])){
    $command = $_POST['command'];
    switch($command){

    case 'getCompanies':
        echo utf8_encode('[["Test1"],["Test2"],["Test3"],["Test4"]]');
        //echo json_encode( $SQLHandler -> getCompanies());
    break;

    }   
}
```

it returns "[["Test1"],["Test2"],["Test3"],["Test4"]]".

However, when I want to analyze the returned String and parse it to an array (with json-simple library), the following occurs:

```
?[["Test1"],["Test2"],["Test3"],["Test4"]]
Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
```

The Java Code is the following:

ArrayList companies = new ArrayList<>();

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/api.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        String content = "command=getCompanies";

        out.writeBytes(content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        is.close();
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(jsonText);
        System.out.println(array);
        System.out.println(array.toJSONString());
        System.out.println(array.toString());
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

It is my first time working with java and json, so it is possible that I did a very easy to find error, but I would be very thankfull if you could point it out to me (and explain what I did wrong;))

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it wasn't an encoding problem at all...
See my modified code:

ArrayList companies = new ArrayList<>();

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/api.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        String content = "command=getCompanies";

        out.writeBytes(content);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        String wholeLine = "";
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            wholeLine = wholeLine + line;
        }

        is.close();
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(wholeLine);

        for(Object obj : array.toArray()){
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

I forgot to supply "line" to the parse function and instead parsed the wrong variable ^^
Regards